# Sub-shells, sub-processes and variables in Linux Pipes vs normal forked commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, pipe

I was trying to understand more about how processes in linux work in their execution environment.
I am reffering strictly to Bash shell and how it interprets things.

So just to see if I understood things correctly:

1. In any command you run in a bash shell that it is not a builtin command, bash should first fork in a subshell copying most of the parent execution enviroment including aliases + unexported shell variables beside other things and then exec( execv() ) the program instance then. For a brief period of time, the child process is still running bash (so somehow we can name it as a "subshell" only for this reason) before calling execv() and executing the program instance.
2. If the command you run is a builtin command, when you run it, the command is executed directly without forking as it is builtin in the bash shell as it will call for example in "cd" the cd_builtin function.
3. In case of pipes, in bash, all the commands are started in their own sub-shells/subprocess like the one explained at point "1." (without forking another bash instance like in case of bash scripts,  ), including the built-in ones ( for example in "cd /etc | echo will" bash will fork first and call cd_builtin in the child like a command that it is not builtin and it will do the same to "echo" part of the pipeline too )
4. I saw that on multiple posts that people, while talking about Shell variables (unexported) vs Exported environment variables tend to use the term  "Sub-shell" for child processes/sub processes too ( like the ones that I was talking about above. For me, seeing that in a forked process from bash (that briefly has a bash subshell before execv()), the command that exec has access to aliases and shell unexported variables creates a bit of confusion while reading that subprocesses will not have access to unexported variables. I am aware of that fact that if I run a bash script, bash will fork another instance of bash and run the script there without having access to the variables that I did not exported or the aliases (as aliases do not export)

Did I understood things correctly? I am aware of the fact that I have missed some things.
Thank you!

Comment: For the last  part, regarding the environment inheriting found a reference in this answer: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell 
In the accepted answer, beside other things it states the following:

"But apart from built-in special cases like these, all variables have the same value in the subshell as in the original shell, the same export status, the same read-only status, etc. All function definitions, alias definitions, shell options and other settings are inherited as well."

Answer (score 0):

> in a forked process from bash (that briefly has a bash subshell before execv()) I can still have access to aliases and shell unexported variables

No, *you* (a bash *user* who writes scripts) cannot. This short-lived code does what it needs to do in order to `exec` a program, nothing more. It is a fixed machine code inside the bash executable, not a script you can control. You cannot make it access aliases and unexported variables. It just doesn't do that.

If you modify the source code of `bash` and insert C code between `fork` and `exec` that accesses these things, then yes, *you* (a bash *author* from now on) could access them. But why would you?

Once `exec` is called, the memory of `bash` is gone, and aliases and shell unexported variables are gone with it for good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was not reffering to me as a bash user but to that actual code, as I saw that in pipes for example, if I want use an alias/parent variable that was not exported, in one of the elements of the pipe, the command that exec in that subshell in the pipe have acces to those. –

Comment: I have edited my answer because you are right, and it is confusing to read.